No module named 'llama_index.vector_stores' - installation of OpenDevin on WSL Ubuntu
I try to install and start OpenDevin on WSL Ubuntu (WSL 2). Ok, I follow this guide but I can't fix this error so the backend doesn't start
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.vector_stores
I use these commands
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh

sudo apt install uvicorn

git clone https://github.com/OpenDevin/OpenDevin.git
cd OpenDevin
conda create -n opendevin python=3.11
conda activate opendevin 
docker ps
docker pull ghcr.io/opendevin/sandbox
which python
python --version
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/opendevin/bin/python -m pip install pipenv
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/opendevin/bin/python -m pipenv install -v
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/opendevin/bin/python -m pipenv shell
uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000

I get this error after uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000 command
Any idea to solve ?
